# Restricted to use modules. How can I compute angles using trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: python-3.x, function, math, geolocation

I have to compute azimuth and bearings of northings and eastings. I already made a functions for it but now we have to modify it because any modules are restricted and I used math.cos(), math.sin(), math.arctan() and math.degrees() in those functions.
How do I modify my code?

This one I made for getting the azimuth from a dictionary of northings and eastings:

```
def azimuth(dct):
    val = getVal(dct)
    lat = val[1]
    dep = val[2]
    az_list = []
    for a in lat:
        az = math.degrees(math.atan((dep[a]/lat[a])))
        if (lat[a] > 0):
            az = az + 180
        elif (lat[a] < 0):
            if (dep[a] > 0):
                az = az + 360
            else:
                az = az
        az_list.append(az)
    return az_list
```

Comment: You can define your own `cos`, `sin`, etc. functions using the Taylor expansions.

Comment: I see you're using lists and numbers. Is there a list of modules that can you use?